# deployed grails war file is not creating tables on weblogic

Tags: java, grails, oracle11g, weblogic

my grails application war file is deployed on Weblogic server version 12 and when I start the service it will apply my changes into created tables(for example it adds some columns or constraints) but when I add some domain classes for **automatic table creation** it won't create them automatically on the application startup.
And when I connect to same database on my local computer with Intellij Idea it creates the corresponding tables to the new added domain classes.
my problem is on the application server, and I have the same hibernate configuration in both development and production environments.

Grails Version 2.2.3
Oracle 11
Weblogic 12
JDK 7

Comment: Have you checked permissions of your production db user? Maybe it's not allowed to create tables.

Comment: What value does `dataSource.dbCreate` have in whatever environment you are using when you build the `.war` file that you are deploying to WebLogic? (normally that value is assigned in `grails-app/conf/DataSource.groovy`).

Comment: @Michal_Szulc Yes My User has the permissions to create and alter tables.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown  dataSource.dbCreate value is 'update' in my project

Comment: set sqllog to true in Datasource.groovy to check the query, and check if you could run it manually in the db.

Comment: "set sqllog to true in Datasource.groovy to check the query,"- FYI... The config property name is `logSql`.